# What is better: one page or some pages?

Tags: seo, links, canonical-url, content, rel-canonical

What do you mean is better in terms of SEO (all aspects of it: internal linking, content, index management):

- to have one page with unique content or
- to have some pages with similar content to the same topic, linking to one of them with internal links and canonical?

Comment: Canonical tags shouldn't be used for similar content, only for duplicate content.

Comment: How much content is on these pages?  It isn't worth splitting up a small amount of content among several pages, but if it it too much for one page, then it is better to have multiple pages.

Comment: pages are similar to 90%. there are 500-600 words on each page. So i don't really know, would it worth to make only one unique, or to leave all near-duplicates for the sake of internal linking

Answer (score 1):

Google's SEO policy is to build websites for humans and not for bots. At the same time, we all know that Googlebot just likes some things more than others. There's a strong argument to be made that you should just develop the website in such a way that is most beneficial to users and then structure the canonical tag for Googlebot aftewards.

Google has been known to reward larger sites than smaller sites. So creating many pages with canonical tags might give you a boost in this way.

But creating pages with a lot of similar content can dilute Googlebot's crawling usage. And because Googlebot is part AI at this point, it seems to me from my experience that if you don't offer the bot any new and original content that it can get bored of your site and start using its crawler on other domains. Googlebot only has so much crawling server capacity and wants to use it as wisely as it can.

Say for instance you have a big site with 100,000 pages and 80% of them have similar content. Google might crawl 20,000 of these pages and decide that they're too much alike to crawl the next 80,000. This is a real possibility.

If you're using the rel=canonical tag then these pages won't get indexed by Google anyway. As a result, you may really want to just put as much bang for your buck content on each individual page.

Pages that have over 1500 words are known to rank higher than pages with under 300 words. If you're diluting your content across multiple pages then this might reduce your SERP position.

If on the other hand you have a page about "cats" and a page about "cat toys" and you're using some of the content on the "cats" page on your "cat toys" page while still adding addition content to the "cat toys" page, I would just try to have Google index both of the pages. You don't want someone who is searching for "cats" to visit your "cat toy" page over your "cats" page. And you don't want someone searching for "cat toys" to be sent to your "cats" page. You want Google to index both.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to do what you want or ask...
But Good depends upon your situation and what you want & why you want...

It will be better that to write a single post with more details that cover all your points.

for example: 
what is seo? 
Why I need seo?
How to do seo?   can write in one post...

But will not be the best option to mix Cat diets, funny Cats....  because different in the nature of the topics....!

Studies found that The more you have content related to a topic on your site, more easy to rank higher.  As Neil Patel said About Piller content strategy...

Stuedies also show that longer content ranks higher than shorter...

So it is bet idea to mix up content which are more relevant to each other and redirect those url to one you have updated...

But not that are not relevant...

Technically and practically it is the best strategy from the viewpoint of seo..

Thanks